# How to pass class member to super classes constructor?

Tags: kotlin

Why is it not possible to pass a member object to the super classes constructor?

This is working:

```
class Foo(private val whatever : Object = Object()) : BaseClass(whatever) {

    fun someFunction() {
        // Do something with "whatever"
        println(whatever.toString())
    }

}
```

But this isn't:

```
class Foo() : BaseClass(whatever) {

    private val whatever = Object()

    fun someFunction() {
        // Do something with "whatever"
        println(whatever.toString())
    }

}
```

The member `whatever` cannot be passed to the base class in the second example. That makes sense because the subclass is initialized after the baseclass and at this time `whatever` does not exist yet. But why is the first example working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [Initialization Order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order).

First example works, because the argument of `BaseClass`'s constructor is an argument of `Foo`'s constructor. There is no problem. Argument is just passed.

Second example is not working because `BaseClass`'s constructor needs to be invoked as a first step before the `Foo`'s `whatever` property is initialized.

**EDIT :**

If you really need to initialize `whatever` inside of `Foo`, then you can use [Companion Object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#companion-objects).

```
class Foo2() : BaseClass(whatever) {

    companion object {
        private val whatever = Object()
    }

}
```

Comment: But where is the object `whatever` created in the first example? And how can I make the second one working, so that `whatever`is not set by subclasses constructor?

Comment: Whatever is created outside of constructor, possibly its default value is used but that is still before the BaseClass is called.

Comment: Why you need to use whatever initialized in Foo? Why not just pass it to the Foo's constructor?

Comment: I need it in some functions in `Foo`.

Comment: I could just pass it and make `whatever` in the BaseClass a `protected val` so I can access it in `Foo`. Maybe this is the cleanest solution..

Answer (score 0):

when creating a subclass of another class you call the constructor of these class, for example `BaseClass(whatever)`. in this case, the `whatever` object is need to be created/passed as parameters in the primary constructor of these subclass.

In kotlin aside from creating the properties inside the class, also you can define it as parameters in the primary constructor using var/val. like `class Foo(val whatever : Object)`

but, its only on the primary constructor.

Comment: I know that I can create properties in the constructor; that is shown in the first example. But the question is, how to move the property to within the class and still pass it to the baseclass?